# Como faço para pegar o valor de um input hidden com jquery

Tags: jquery

Consegui gerar dinamicamente uma tabela com alguns campos ocultos que não podem aparecer. Mas estou com dificuldade de buscar esses campos para depois enviá-los para um post. Segue o codigo html gerado.

```
<tr>
<td>Tenis Azul</td>
<td>35</td>
<td>99.99</td>
<td>Admin</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="true"></td>
<td><a class="botao-remover btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="#"></a></td>
<input type="hidden" value="1">
<input type="hidden" value="35">
<input type="hidden" value="99.99">
<input type="hidden" value="1">
<input type="hidden" value="1">
</tr>
```

Eu tenho vários  gerados como esse. Mas na hora de selecionar os values eu não sei como buscar para armazenar em variáveis. Já tentei .attr("value").val()
mas não da certo.

```
var linhas = $("tbody>tr");
  linhas.each(function(){
    var id_produto = $(this).find("input:nth-child(1)").attr("value").val();
    console.log(id_produto);
  });
```

Erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).attr(...).val is not a function
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já agradeço

Comment: Se for enviado por POST por um `<form>` seria só atribuir um `name` aos inputs que o próprio form enviaria para o servidor.

Comment: Cara, nem passou pela minha cabeça isso. Acho que resolve tranquilamente. Vou tentar aqui. Obrigado

Comment: Pensando bem o ideal seria ler todas as <tr> mesmo e fazer um array para enviar por Post.

Comment: Não precisa ler todas as **tr** pode pegar o valor dos inputs diretamente.

Comment: Se todos os inputs tiverem o mesmo `name` o servidor receberá como um array.

Comment: Não posso ler eles diretamente, pois eu os crio dinamicamente pra preencher uma linha de uma tabela. Se minha tabela gerar 10 linha por exemplo serão 50 inputs. Não vejo como ler diretamente pois a intenção é pegar essas linhas depois e inserir no banco de dados

Answer (score 2):

O seletor :hidden resolve seu problema. Inclusive, conforme o exemplo, ele consegue pegar elementos com atributo `hidden` ou `display:none`

```js
$('input:hidden').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="hidden" value="1">
  <input type="text" hidden value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" value="3">
```

> https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é definir uma classe para os campos `hidden` e depois fazer um loop

```js
$('.escodido').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Tenis Azul</td>
  <td>35</td>
  <td>99.99</td>
  <td>Admin</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="true"></td>
  <td>
    <a class="botao-remover btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="#"></a>
  </td>
  <input type="hidden" class="escodido" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" class="escodido" value="35">
  <input type="hidden" class="escodido" value="99.99">
  <input type="hidden" class="escodido" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" class="escodido" value="1">
</tr>
```

Comment: Solucionou certinho. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
function getHiddens() {
    var hiddens = $("table#tabMinhasTarefas input[type='hidden']");
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddens.length; i++) {
         alert(hiddens[i].value);
    }
}
```

Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Se o que você quer é enviar estes inputs ao servidor não há necessidade de usar JS pra isso, basta que você atribua os `name`s corretamente.

O servidor sabe que inputs com nomes repetidos são arrays (a não ser que você use PHP aí teria usar `[]`).

Aqui vai um exemplo onde utilizo o serviço [HttpBin](https://httpbin.org/) para mostrar os dados que o servidor recebe.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#add')
const tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody')
const linha_modelo = tbody.querySelector('tr')

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let clone = linha_modelo.cloneNode(true)
    tbody.appendChild(clone)
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="https://httpbin.org/post">

  <button id="add" type="button">Adicionar linha</button>
  
  <hr>
  
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Coluna</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Linhas dinâmicas com input hidden
          <input type="hidden" name="input-hidden-1" value="valor teste">
          <input type="hidden" name="input-hidden-2" value="valor teste">
          <input type="hidden" name="input-hidden-3" value="valor teste">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <hr>
  
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Docs dos conceitos utilizados:

- [HttpBin dump dos dados do POST](https://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods/post_post)
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/querySelector)
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Use um id nos campos que você precisa receber o valor
Ex

```
<input type="hidden" id="valor1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="valor2" value="35">
<input type="hidden" id="valor3" value="99.99">
<input type="hidden" id="valor4" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="valor5" value="1">
```

Em seguida pode usar js ou jquery para receber o valor que você precisa.
Ex

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var valor1 = null;
    var valor2 = null;
    var valor3 = null;
    var valor4 = null;
    var valor5 = null;

    $(function() {
        // como vc pode receber o valor de um campo tipo hidden
        $('#valor1').val();
        $('#valor2').val();
        $('#valor3').val();
        $('#valor4').val();
        $('#valor5').val();
        // salvando em uma variavel que foi defida acima VAR valor...
        valor1 = $('#valor1').val();
        valor2 = $('#valor2').val();
        valor3 = $('#valor3').val();
        valor4 = $('#valor4').val();
        valor5 = $('#valor5').val();
        // aqui vc verifica se está recebendo o valor do input
        console.log(valor1);
    });
});
```